# TypeError: x(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, components

I am trying to unit test my component that calls a service method in ngOnInit. When I try to run the test I get the error:

TypeError: this.adminService.getTestString(...).subscribe is not a function

Following are the files for reference.

app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ISAppAdmin';

  greet: String;
  errorMessage: String;
  constructor(private adminService: AdminService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.adminService.getTestString().subscribe(
      data => this.greet = data,
      error => this.errorMessage = < any > error
    )

    this.adminService.putTestString().subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      error => this.errorMessage = < any > error
    )

    console.log("in app");
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log("button clicked");
    this.router.navigate(['admin']);
    console.log("still on same page");
  }

}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```js
class MockAdminService {
  res = "Hello World";
  getTestString() {
    return this.res;
  }
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let mockAdminService: MockAdminService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture < AppComponent > ;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{
        provide: AdminService,
        useClass: MockAdminService
      }],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    mockAdminService = new MockAdminService();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //mockAdminService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getTestString']);

  }));
  it('should receive Hello World when getTestString is called', () => {
    let testData = "Hello World";
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(this.component.greet).toEqual(testData);
  });
});
```

admin.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/test';
  data: String;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  getTestString(): Observable < any > {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
    });
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/rest/test", {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'text'
    });
  }
}
```

```js
Chrome 65.0 .3325(Windows 10.0 .0) AppComponent should receive Hello World when getTestString is called FAILED
TypeError: this.adminService.getTestString(...).subscribe is not a
function
at AppComponent.ngOnInit(webpack: ///./src/app/app.component.ts?:26:43)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline(webpack: ///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9547:19)
      at checkAndUpdateNodeInline(webpack: ///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10811:20)
        at checkAndUpdateNode(webpack: ///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10773:16)
          at debugCheckAndUpdateNode(webpack: ///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11406:38)
            at debugCheckDirectivesFn(webpack: ///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11366:13)
              at Object.eval[as updateDirectives](ng: ///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9:9)
                at Object.debugUpdateDirectives[as updateDirectives](webpack: ///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11358:21)
                  at checkAndUpdateView(webpack: ///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10755:14)
```

Can someone please help me understand my mistake and how to correct it.

Thank you

Comment: `AdminService` returns an observable by doing `return this.http.get(...)`. But `MockAdminService` doesn't return an observable.

Comment: create a spy on the `MockAdminService` to return the Observable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mock service doesn't return an observable:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

class MockAdminService {
  res = "Hello World";

  getTestString() {
    return of(this.res);
  }
}
```

Comment: Returning observable was the solution. Thank you for your help.